# Group by field of document from embedded array then by field of parent document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-3.6

I'm not sure how to phrase this, but basically I want to group documents by a field from a child array, then I want to group by a field in the parent (root) document, but retaining the prior grouping.

I hope an example would help here.

Let's say I have these documents, where informations about several `custItemNum` are almost grouped by `originalFile`:

```
[
    {
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "recType" : "I2",
                "qty" : 2.0,
                "custItemNum" : 10.0
            }, 
            {
                "recType" : "I2",
                "qty" : 200.0,
                "custItemNum" : 20.0
            }, 
            {
                "recType" : "I2",
                "qty" : 50.0,
                "custItemNum" : 30.0
            }, 
            {
                "recType" : "D9",
                "custItemNum" : 10.0
            }, 
            {
                "recType" : "D9",
                "custItemNum" : 20.0
            }, 
            {
                "recType" : "D9",
                "custItemNum" : 30.0
            }
        ],
        "originalFile" : "727451921.txt",
        "docId" : "278791399"
    },
    {
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "recType" : "I2",
                "qty" : 180.0,
                "custItemNum" : 20.0
            }
        ],
        "originalFile" : "727557371.txt",
        "docId" : "278791399"
    },
    {
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "recType" : "I2",
                "qty" : 10.0,
                "custItemNum" : 30.0
            }
        ],
        "originalFile" : "727557371.txt",
        "docId" : "278791399"
    },
    {
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "recType" : "I2",
                "qty" : 10.0,
                "custItemNum" : 30.0
            }
        ],
        "originalFile" : "727557371.txt",
        "docId" : "278791399"
    }
]
```

I want to end up with a collection like this, where the first grouping is by `custItemNumber` and then by `originalFile`:

```
[
    {
        "custItemNumber" : 10.0,
        "count" : 2.0,
        "itemInfo" : [ 
            {
                "originalFile" : "727451921.txt",
                "item" : [ 
                    {
                        "recType" : "I2",
                        "qty" : 2.0,
                        "custItemNum" : 10.0
                    }, 
                    {
                        "recType" : "D9",
                        "custItemNum" : 10.0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "custItemNumber" : 20.0,
        "count" : 3.0,
        "itemInfo" : [ 
            {
                "originalFile" : "727451921.txt",
                "item" : [ 
                    {
                        "recType" : "I2",
                        "qty" : 200.0,
                        "custItemNum" : 20.0
                    }, 
                    {
                        "recType" : "D9",
                        "custItemNum" : 20.0
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "originalFile" : "727557371.txt",
                "item" : [ 
                    {
                        "recType" : "I2",
                        "qty" : 180.0,
                        "custItemNum" : 20.0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "custItemNumber" : 30.0,
        "count" : 4.0,
        "itemInfo" : [ 
            {
                "originalFile" : "727451921.txt",
                "item" : [ 
                    {
                        "recType" : "I2",
                        "qty" : 50.0,
                        "custItemNum" : 30.0
                    }, 
                    {
                        "recType" : "D9",
                        "custItemNum" : 30.0
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "originalFile" : "727557371.txt",
                "item" : [ 
                    {
                        "recType" : "I2",
                        "qty" : 10.0,
                        "custItemNum" : 30.0
                    }, 
                    {
                        "recType" : "I2",
                        "qty" : 10.0,
                        "custItemNum" : 30.0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Bear in mind that these documents already come from several aggregation steps so no useful `_id` field is available.

So far I came up with these aggregation stages (and I manually edited its output to obtain the result above):

```
{$unwind: "$items"},
{$bucket: {
    groupBy: "$items.custItemNum",
    boundaries: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
    output: {
        count: {$sum: 1},
        itemInfo: {$push: "$$ROOT"}
    }
 }}
```

that leads to this result:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : 10.0,
        "count" : 2.0,
        "itemInfo" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a7336ebb4b169272dae528f"),
                "items" : {
                    "recType" : "I2",
                    "qty" : 2.0,
                    "custItemNum" : 10.0
                },
                "originalFile" : "727451921.txt",
                "docId" : "278791399"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a7336ebb4b169272dae528f"),
                "items" : {
                    "recType" : "D9",
                    "custItemNum" : 10.0
                },
                "originalFile" : "727451921.txt",
                "docId" : "278791399"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : 20.0,
        "count" : 3.0,
        "itemInfo" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a7336ebb4b169272dae528f"),
                "items" : {
                    "recType" : "I2",
                    "qty" : 200.0,
                    "custItemNum" : 20.0
                },
                "originalFile" : "727451921.txt",
                "docId" : "278791399"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a7336ebb4b169272dae528f"),
                "items" : {
                    "recType" : "D9",
                    "custItemNum" : 20.0
                },
                "originalFile" : "727451921.txt",
                "docId" : "278791399"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a7336ebb4b169272dae5290"),
                "items" : {
                    "recType" : "I2",
                    "qty" : 180.0,
                    "custItemNum" : 20.0
                },
                "originalFile" : "727557371.txt",
                "docId" : "278791399"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : 30.0,
        "count" : 4.0,
        "itemInfo" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a7336ebb4b169272dae528f"),
                "items" : {
                    "recType" : "I2",
                    "qty" : 50.0,
                    "custItemNum" : 30.0
                },
                "originalFile" : "727451921.txt",
                "docId" : "278791399"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a7336ebb4b169272dae528f"),
                "items" : {
                    "recType" : "D9",
                    "custItemNum" : 30.0
                },
                "originalFile" : "727451921.txt",
                "docId" : "278791399"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a7336ebb4b169272dae5291"),
                "items" : {
                    "recType" : "I2",
                    "qty" : 10.0,
                    "custItemNum" : 30.0
                },
                "originalFile" : "727557371.txt",
                "docId" : "278791399"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a7336ebb4b169272dae5292"),
                "items" : {
                    "recType" : "I2",
                    "qty" : 10.0,
                    "custItemNum" : 30.0
                },
                "originalFile" : "727557371.txt",
                "docId" : "278791399"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm stuck here, any other step that comes to mind (i.e. a `$replaceRoot : { newRoot: "$itemInfo" }` ) would break the outer grouping.

Plus, the `custItemNum` values are dynamic, but AFAICT the `boundaries` field of the `$bucket` stage takes a constant array, so if there's a way to pass a computed array there, I'd like to know how.